# CSS "overflow:hidden" doesnt work

Tags: html, css

Having touble with "Overflow: hidden". Don't understand why it is not working. Overflow text still shows.

What can be the problem?

PS: I am a biginner. Thank you for any help =)

```css
.nextArticle {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  
  margin-top: 98px;
  margin-bottom: 58px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 62px;
  
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #4ada92;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nextArticle a {
  color: white;
}

.nextArticle::before {
  content: "Whats next: ";
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nextArticle">
  
  <a href="#">isque viverra vulputate aliquet. In eleifend arcu at lectus dictum, dictum egestas arcu dignissim. isque viverra vulputate aliquet. In eleifend arcu at lectus dictum, dictum egestas arcu dignissim. isque viverra vulputate aliquet. In eleifend arcu at lectus dictum, dictum egestas arcu dignissim.</a>

</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It looks like its working correctly based on your example. Please explain what the intended *outcome* is rather than just "it's not working"

Comment: sorry. overflow:hidden - doesnt work

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin It works as expected in the example you posted. What browser are you viewing this in? How exactly *isn't* it working?

Comment: may be cuz its hidden try making it visible, everything looks fine

Comment: @JoshCrozier please check now

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin still works fine :)

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that's not happening?

Comment: @op post a screen shot of the problem as you see it, or if you dont have enough reputation then upload it somewhere and post a link.